# Find $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous and positive number, such that there is a real number $c$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)x^{k}dx=c^k$, for $k={0,1,...,n}$  , (1). For a function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, continuous, find $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$ and show that $c\in[0,1]$. Because the integrand (1) is bounded below by $0$, $c\geq0$ and by the mean value theorem, there is an $a\in[0,1]$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)x^{k}dx=\frac{f(a)}{k+1}$, and from here by the fact that for $lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(a)}{k+1}=0$, $lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}  c^k=0$ and so $c$ can't be bigger than $1$. However, I am unable to use this in proving the second task.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the hypothesis should be for all $k \neq 0$. If it is for $0\leq k \leq n$ for some fixed $n$ it is not possible to determine $\int_0^{1}f(x)g(x)\, dx$.

For any polynomial $p$ we get $\int_0^{1}f(x)p(x)\, dx=p(c)$ by just taking linear combinations. By Weierstrass theorem $g$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomials. This gives $\int_0^{1}f(x)g(x)\, dx=g(c)$.